# Websocket performance issue on iOS 11

Tags: ios, websocket, ios11

I have a websocket server and I run in a html page the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<title>In/Out: Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket;

function onLoad() {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://10.10.10.1:80", "inout");
    socket.onopen = function() {
        socket.send("update");
    }

    var previous = 0;
    socket.onmessage = function got_packet(msg) {
        var now = Date.now();
        var st = "" + (now - previous) + " ms";
        previous = now;
        console.log(st);
        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = st;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
<span id="debug" name="debug" style="font-size:300%"></span></body></html>
```

The server sends messages at least every 100ms.

Everywhere (Windows, Linux, Android, even MacOS), it's working very well, I receive messages at the same rate.

On iOS 11 (iPod touch, iPhone), with ANY browser (Safari, Chrome) it's extremely slow and I receive messages at best every 1200ms.

Here are two devices (Android phone and iPod touch 6th gen):
[image]

This report ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/52tyz5/ios_10_did_websockets_change/)) seems to be similar to my problem.

Any idea what could be the issue? Anyone experiencing the same problem?